# Trying to use EhCache using Spring and a custom GenericDao interface that extends the Hibernate's JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ehcache, genericdao

**Background**

Here is my working (simplified) `GenericDao` interface, which is implemented by any `DomainDao`:

*GenericDao.java*

```java
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface GenericDao<E extends Persistable<K>, K extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<E, K> {

    public List<E> findAll();

    public E persist(E entity);

}
```

*GenericDaoImpl.java*

```java
public class GenericDaoImpl<E extends Persistable<K>, K extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<E, K> implements GenericDao<E, K> {

    private final JpaEntityInformation<E, ?> entityInformation;
    private final EntityManager em;
    private final Class<E> type;

    public GenericDaoImpl(JpaEntityInformation<E, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager em) {
        super(entityInformation, em);
        this.entityInformation = entityInformation;
        this.em = em;
        this.type = entityInformation.getJavaType();
    }

    @Override
    public List<E> findAll() {
        return super.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public E persist(E entity) {
        if (entityInformation.isNew(entity) || !EntityUtils.isPrimaryKeyGenerated(type) && !em.contains(entity)) {
            em.persist(entity);
        }
        return entity;
    }

}
```

For example, to manage the domains `Foo` and `Bar`, you just need to create two interfaces as follow:

*FooDao.java*

```java
public interface FooDao extends GenericDao<Foo, Integer> {

}
```

*BarDao.java*

```java
public interface BarDao extends GenericDao<Bar, Integer> {

}
```

The [`@Autowired`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) annotation of `Spring` will automatically instantiate a `GenericDaoImpl` with the good entity and primary key types.

---

**Problem**

I'm now trying to add a caching process on my DAOs, using EhCache and the [EhCache Spring Annotations](http://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/) model.

*GenericDao.java*

```java
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface GenericDao<E extends Persistable<K>, K extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<E, K> {

    @Cacheable(cacheName = "dao")
    public List<E> findAll();

    @TriggersRemove(cacheName = "dao")
    public E persist(E entity);

}
```

*applicationContext.xml*

```xml
<ehcache:annotation-driven cache-manager="ehCacheManager" />    
<bean id="ehCacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" />
```

*ehcache.xml*

```xml
<cache name="dao"
    eternal="false"
    maxElementsInMemory="10000"
    overflowToDisk="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="86400"
    timeToLiveSeconds="86400"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />
```

The problem with the use of a `GenericDao`, is that the cache should manage each `DomainDao` independently of each other. For example, with the current configuration, if I call `fooDao.findAll()`, and then `barDao.persist(new Bar())`, the cache generated by `fooDao.findAll()` will be reset, since the same cache would have been used (i.e. `<cache name="dao" />`), while it shouldn't.

---

**Trails**

I tried to implement my own [`CacheKeyGenerator`](http://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/wiki/CacheKeyGenerators), that will take into account the type of the calling `DomainDao`:

*applicationContext.xml*

```xml
<ehcache:annotation-driven cache-manager="ehCacheManager" default-cache-key-generator="daoCacheKeyGenerator" />    
<bean id="ehCacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" />
<bean id="daoCacheKeyGenerator" class="myapp.dao.support.DaoCacheKeyGenerator" />
```

*DaoCacheKeyGenerator.java*

```java
public class DaoCacheKeyGenerator implements CacheKeyGenerator<DaoCacheKey> {

    @Override
    public DaoCacheKey generateKey(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) {
        Class<?> clazz = methodInvocation.getThis().getClass().getInterfaces()[0];
        Method method = methodInvocation.getMethod();
        String methodName = method.getName();
        Class<?>[] parameterClasses = method.getParameterTypes();
        return new DaoCacheKey(clazz, methodName, parameterClasses);
    }

    @Override
    public DaoCacheKey generateKey(Object... data) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

*DaoCacheKey.java*

```java
public class DaoCacheKey implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 338466521373614710L;

    private Class<?> clazz;
    private String methodName;
    private Class<?>[] parameterClasses;

    public DaoCacheKey(Class<?> clazz, String methodName, Class<?>[] parameterClasses) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.methodName = methodName;
        this.parameterClasses = parameterClasses;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) { // <-- breakpoint
        if (obj instanceof DaoCacheKey) {
            DaoCacheKey other = (DaoCacheKey) obj;
            if (clazz.equals(other.clazz)) {
                // if @TriggersRemove, reset any cache generated by a find* method of the same DomainDao
                boolean removeCache = !methodName.startsWith("find") && other.methodName.startsWith("find");
                // if @Cacheable, check if the result has been previously cached
                boolean getOrCreateCache = methodName.equals(other.methodName) && Arrays.deepEquals(parameterClasses, other.parameterClasses);
                return removeCache || getOrCreateCache;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() { // <-- breakpoint
        return super.hashCode();
    }

}
```

The problem with the above `DaoCacheKey`, is that the `equals` method get never called (the program never breaks at least), but the `hashCode` one does, so the algorithm can't get applied.

---

**Question**

Has anyone already managed such a cache? If yes how? Does my try is relevant? If yes, how to make the `equals` method called, instead of the `hashCode` one? By extending an existing [`CacheKeyGenerator`](http://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/wiki/CacheKeyGenerators)? If yes, which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working solution I finally adopted. Just few precisions: my domains all implement the [`Persistable`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Persistable.html) interface of Spring. Moreover, since I'm using reflection, I'm not sure the time saved by the caching process won't be a bit reduced...

*applicationContext.xml*

```xml
<ehcache:annotation-driven cache-manager="ehCacheManager" default-cache-key-generator="daoCacheKeyGenerator" />    
<bean id="ehCacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" />
<bean id="daoCacheKeyGenerator" class="myapp.dao.support.cache.DaoCacheKeyGenerator" />
```

*DaoCacheKeyGenerator.java (using the [gentyref](http://code.google.com/p/gentyref/) library)*

```java
public class DaoCacheKeyGenerator implements CacheKeyGenerator<DaoCacheKey> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public DaoCacheKey generateKey(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) {
        Method method = methodInvocation.getMethod();
        Class<? extends GenericDao<?, ?>> daoType = (Class<? extends GenericDao<?, ?>>) methodInvocation.getThis().getClass().getInterfaces()[0];
        Class<? extends Persistable<?>> domainType = getDomainType(daoType);
        String methodName = method.getName();
        Class<?>[] parameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
        Object[] parameters = methodInvocation.getArguments();
        return new DaoCacheKey(domainType, methodName, parameterTypes, parameters);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Class<? extends Persistable<?>> getDomainType(Class<?> daoType) {
        Type baseDaoType = GenericTypeReflector.getExactSuperType(daoType, GenericDao.class);
        ParameterizedType parameterizedBaseDaoType = (ParameterizedType) baseDaoType;
        return (Class<? extends Persistable<?>>) parameterizedBaseDaoType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    @Override
    public DaoCacheKey generateKey(Object... data) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

*DaoCacheKey.java*

```java
public class DaoCacheKey implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 338466521373614710L;

    private Class<? extends Persistable<?>> domainType;
    private String methodName;
    private Class<?>[] parameterTypes;
    private Object[] parameters;

    public DaoCacheKey(Class<? extends Persistable<?>> domainType, String methodName, Class<?>[] parameterTypes, Object[] parameters) {
        this.domainType = domainType;
        this.methodName = methodName;
        this.parameterTypes = parameterTypes;
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }

    public Class<? extends Persistable<?>> getDomainType() {
        return domainType;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return this == obj || obj instanceof DaoCacheKey && hashCode() == obj.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(new Object[] { domainType, methodName, Arrays.asList(parameterTypes), Arrays.asList(parameters) });
    }

}
```

*ehcache.xml*

```xml
<cache name="dao"
    eternal="false"
    maxElementsInMemory="10000"
    overflowToDisk="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="86400"
    timeToLiveSeconds="86400"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">
    <cacheEventListenerFactory class="myapp.dao.support.cache.DaoCacheEventListenerFactory" />
</cache>
```

*DaoCacheEventListenerFactory.java*

```java
public class DaoCacheEventListenerFactory extends CacheEventListenerFactory {

    @Override
    public CacheEventListener createCacheEventListener(Properties properties) {
        return new DaoCacheEventListener();
    }

}
```

*DaoCacheEventListener.java*

```java
public class DaoCacheEventListener implements CacheEventListener {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void notifyElementRemoved(Ehcache cache, Element element) throws CacheException {
        DaoCacheKey daoCachekey = (DaoCacheKey) element.getKey();
        List<Class<? extends Persistable<?>>> impacts = getOneToManyImpacts(daoCachekey.getDomainType());
        for (DaoCacheKey daoCachedkey : (List<DaoCacheKey>) cache.getKeys()) {
            if (impacts.contains(daoCachedkey.getDomainType())) {
                cache.remove(daoCachedkey);
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private List<Class<? extends Persistable<?>>> getOneToManyImpacts(Class<? extends Persistable<?>> domainType) {
        List<Class<? extends Persistable<?>>> impacts = new ArrayList<Class<? extends Persistable<?>>>();
        impacts.add(domainType);
        for (Method method : domainType.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            if (method.isAnnotationPresent(OneToMany.class)) {
                ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) method.getGenericReturnType();
                Class<? extends Persistable<?>> impactedDomainType = (Class<? extends Persistable<?>>) parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
                if (!impacts.contains(impactedDomainType)) {
                    impacts.addAll(getOneToManyImpacts(impactedDomainType));
                }
            }
        }
        return impacts;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyElementPut(Ehcache cache, Element element) throws CacheException {
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyElementUpdated(Ehcache cache, Element element) throws CacheException {
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyElementExpired(Ehcache cache, Element element) {
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyElementEvicted(Ehcache cache, Element element) {
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyRemoveAll(Ehcache cache) {
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
    }

    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }

}
```

Hope that could help `;)`

Comment: Did you run into a situation in your application where you have to implement a way to invalidate single entries in your caches at the GenericDao level? I would be interested to know what the implementation is.