# Spring cache with reflect method

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache, key-generator

I am trying to access a custom key generator to generate key for caching by using a method in cache abstraction doc, but till now I have not found any solution...here I am giving my code

`@Cacheable(value = "itemsCache", key ="T(com.ernst.transactionsAPI.IndexKeyGenerator).generate(#root.target, #root.method.name, #root.args[0])")

    public List<FilialenImpl> getOutletByCustomSearchCache(SearchParametersImpl searchParameters);`

and I am getting following error:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 47): Method call: Method generate(com.ernst.transactionsImpl.filialen.FilialenServiceBean,java.lang.String,com.ernst.persistenceImpl.impl.SearchParametersImpl) cannot be found on com.ernst.transactionsAPI.IndexKeyGenerator type
```

its not reflecting the method name but its passing the method type..can any one please how to solve this problem.

method in indexkeygenerator looks like

```
public Object generate(Object target, Method method, Object... params) {
 ...}
```

Thanks in Advance,

Regards,
Rajasekhar.

Comment: A couple of blind guesses: you are passing a method name (a String) where a Method is expected; you are calling a non-static method on a class.

Comment: actually I have used the spel context to pass a method (i.e. #root.method.name)..but its not happening the way I am expecting.

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14259165/1225328), you could find some interesting stuff for the problem your facing.

Comment: the above solution looks good..but am trying to access the method in  a key generator class by using the following code "T(com.ernst.transactionsAPI.IndexKeyGenerator).generate(#root.target, #root.method.name, #root.args[0])") #root.method.name have to reflect method with object Method but its passing string object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a static method generateKey in IndexKeyGenerator class and called it directly
as shown in following code..then the custom cache for individual caching works just perfect

`@Cacheable(value = "itemsCache", key ="T(com.ernst.transactionsAPI.IndexKeyGenerator).generateKey(#root.target, #root.method, #root.args[0])")
public List<FilialenImpl> getOutletByCustomSearchCache(SearchParametersImpl searchParameters);`

don't forget to override the SearchParameters class.